# Write string that include \n \t in syslog

Tags: linux, c, syslog

Does any one know if it's possible to write a string that contains characters `\n` and `\t` in `syslog`?

I used a C program and I tried to create a string variable that contains `\n` and `\t`.
Then I tried to `cat` the `syslog` file and the result was not what I intended to do. In the syslog those characters are replaced with `#012` and `#011`. I did found some scripts that use regex in order to read that file in a pleasant way but this is not what I need.
What I need is to write in the syslog the string with specified identation.

Here is an example of what I wanted to do:

```
#include <syslog.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char *myMessage = "This is the first line\n This is the second line\n \tThis is the third line\n";
    syslog(LOG_ERR, "My message is: %s", myMessage);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is what I get after I `cat` the `syslog`:

```
test: My message is: This is the first line#012 This is the second line#012 #011This is the third line
```

Here is what I want to get after I `cat` the `syslog`:

```
test: My message is: This is the first line
This is the second line
    This is the third line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syslog messages are implicitly *one line*.
If you want multiple lines, send multiple syslog messages, or, preferably, make your messages shorter.
As the syslog format (e.g. date & time format) is configurable, you cannot set the indent correctly in the sender.